# How to give hsl color value to an svg element

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to ask that If have read that it is possible to give hsl color value to an svg element.But when I try it like this

```
var color = hsl(0, 100%, 50%);

circle.attr("fill" , color);
```

I got an error "unexpected number"

Can any one guide what is the correct way and also does svg supports all hsl colors

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply

```
var color = hsl(0,100%,50%);
```

line means, that you call `hsl` function with `0` ,`100%`, `50%` parameters, and assign returned value to `color` variable.

You need to use quotes, and pass color as a `string`:

```
 var color = "hsl(0, 100%, 50%)";

 circle.attr("fill" , color);
```

For more information about `HSL`, read [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color).

And it doesn't metter whether the hsl color is used by `SVG`, or by other element. It's just a syntax for specifing `color`.

**UPDATE:** To give `color` variable random behavior, try something like this:

```
var color = "hsl("+[0,0,0].map(function(){   return Math.round(100*Math.random())+"%"; }).join(',')+")";
```

Comment: If anyone cares, the generated random color is not valid. Hue range is between 0-360 and it's in angles, not percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if you're using a JavaScript library there, but that doesn't look like valid JS syntax to me. I tried this and it seems to work:

```
var color = "hsl(0, 100%, 50%)";    // use quotes around the value, since there's no hsl() function
circle.setAttribute("fill", color); // setAttribute(), not attr()
// this also works and is better than setAttribute()
circle.style.fill = "hsl(120, 50%, 50%)";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function called hsl() in Javascript neither fill is an attribute.
It's a CSS style. 
in HTML try it the following way:-

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="fill:hsl(0, 100%, 50%);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Also, it seems you are using jQuery or other similar Javascript Library, Thus try the following code:-

```
var color = "hsl(0, 100%, 50%)";
circle.css("fill" , color);
```

Comment: In SVG fill *is* an attribute that is mapped to the equivalent CSS style.